# Swift 2 - function as parameter in function

Tags: function, parameters, swift2

I have a function that as parameters has two other functions.
The code I have works fine however, when I call the function I would love to see the name of the parameters.

This is my function:

```
func dispatchSuperMain(global_queue:()->(), main_queue:()->()) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

            global_queue()

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                main_queue()

            })

        })
    }
```

I call the function using: (working)

```
dispatchSuperMain({ () -> () in
            //global_queue code
            }) { () -> () in
            //main_queue code
}
```

How can I format the function in order to see the name of the parameters ?

for example i would like to call my function like: (not working)

```
dispatchSuperMain( global_queue: { () -> () in
            //global_queue code
            }) main_queue: { () -> () in
            //main_queue code
}
```

Comment: [try this](https://github.com/khoiln/RunKit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions/closures as arguments to higher order function works under the same rules as normal type arguments to regular functions. The addition for higher order functions is that you may place that last closure as a trailing closure, placed outside and after the parantheses when calling the functions (as you have done for the second function argument in your example above).

Anyway, for the first function parameter in your higher order function, explicitly add an external parameter name (otherwise left out for first arguments to functions). For using the already existing external parameter name of the 2nd function parameter, simply place both closures within the function parantheses when calling it.

As an example, consider

```
func f(fun1 fun1: (Int) -> (Int), fun2: (Int) -> (Int)) -> Int {

    let a = 1
    let b = fun1(a)
    let c = fun2(a)

    return b+c
}

let a = f(fun1: { 2*$0 }, fun2: { 3*$0 } )

print(a) // 5
```

Or, a simplified version of your `void`-function example

```
func g(global_queue global_queue: () -> (), main_queue: () -> ()) {
    global_queue() // prints "global"
    main_queue() // prints "main"
}

g(global_queue: { print("global") }, main_queue: { print("main") })
```

If you choose you call your function with the final closure as trailing, I don't think it's possible to use its external parameter name. This is somewhat implicitly explained as we're allowed to use a trailing closure without using external name for this closure, even if it's not the functions first argument. E.g. for regular functions, we must always provide external names to function calls (for arguments other than the first), unless we explicitly add prefix `_` to the corresponding parameters in the functions signature.

```
func h(a: Int, b: Int) {} 
h(1, 2)    // error: missing argument label 'b:' in call
h(1, b: 2) // ok

func hI(a a: Int, _ b: Int) {}
hI(1, 2) // ok
```

Comment: @SNos happy to help!